# PHP Search JSON File

Tags: php, json

So far I have this:

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("URLTOJSONFILEHERE"), true);

$termStr = "WORD TO SEARCHHERE";
$terms = explode(" ", $termStr);

$results = array_filter($obj, function ($x) use ($terms){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        if (stripos($x["label"], $term) ||
            stripos($x["paper_item_id"], $term))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});

echo print_r($results);
```

It does it correctly but how can I do it without print_r and json_encode? Is there a way to put it in an html table? 
The Result I get:

```
{"103":{"paper_item_id":215,"type":5,"cost":320,"is_member":true,"label":"Life Jacket","prompt":"Life Jacket","layer":3000},"120":{"paper_item_id":232,"type":5,"cost":700,"is_member":true,"label":"Green Suede Jacket","prompt":"Green Suede Jacket","layer":3000},"125":{"paper_item_id":237,"type":5,"cost":700,"is_member":true,"label":"Red Suede Jacket","prompt":"Red Suede Jacket","layer":3000},"126":{"paper_item_id":238,"type":5,"cost":700,"is_member":true,"label":"Pastel Suede Jacket","prompt":"Pastel Suede Jacket","layer":3000},"129":{"paper_item_id":241,"type":5,"cost":700,"is_member":true,"label":"Purple Suede Jacket","prompt":"Purple Suede Jacket","layer":3000}
```

What does the First numbers of the JSON mean: 103,120 etc
How can I NOT Show it in JSON file form?

Comment: There is a good bit of information you are not sharing with us. What does the JSON file look like? What is it's source? You're being forced to use `print_r` because you're printing an array or object rather than a string. My suggestion. Once you've got the JSON object into the PHP script, quickly convert it to a standard PHP array that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a JSON encoded array. the 103, 120 are either index references or array keys. Once you have used json_decode, you can just iterate through the resulting array and output the contents. HEre is some psuedo code:

```
$obj = json_decode("...");
foreach($obj as $key=>$value){

  echo $value['paper_item_id'];
  echo $value['type'];
  etc.......

}
```

Of course you will also want to add the HTML mark-up around this.